# For Next loops with Exit For

Tags: excel, vba

For Next loops wtih "Exit For": There is something wrong - maybe something with the position of the "next i" and "end if". The code should "exit for" the if the second "next for" loop = If Cells(TF, 3) = KPF, but not the first "next for" - at least not before i = 10.

```
Sub Udv()
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim TF As Integer
    Dim KPF As String
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KP").Select
    For i = 1 To 10
        'KPF = Cells(i, 1).Value
        KPF = Worksheets("KP").Cells(i, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RABAT").Select
        lrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lrow
            TF = Int((lrow * Rnd) + 1)
            If Cells(TF, 3).Value = KPF Then
                Cells(TF, 2).Copy
                Worksheets("KP").Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RABAT").Select
                If Cells(TF, 3) = KPF Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are both of your`For` loops using `i`?

Comment: Also, even if you substitute in a different variable name for the second `i` - you don't appear to be using it or anything else inside your secondary loop? The only reason you loop at all is presumably to hit multiple random rows with `TF` ?

Comment: Hi Brax; I thought that using same "i" wouldt be a problem.

Comment: VBA won't even allow you to run the routine to test it, if it sees a control variable already in use it will error. So have you not tested your routine at all?

Comment: "i" is only used inside the single loops. Yes in the second loop I only loop again if value in cells(TF,3) is not = KPF. And if cells(TF,3) = KPF., it should stop second loop and proces the first loop (like; i=2,...).

Comment: @ASKASK - You can use two `i`s but the inner loop sets the value of the outer one. It's unlikely that's what you want.

Comment: Right - tried to change i with j in inner loop, however it dident help

Comment: Just want to stop inner loop (and return to first loop) if the value in the random row is = the defined variable value (=KPF) (set at running the first loop).

Comment: @ASKASK - I didn't say it would help, but it certainly was something to fix.